# get and call custom object method

Tags: jquery

I am familiar with jquery, but not so advanced.
I have webpage where it creates some jquery object (CLButton). Here is full js code (http://contactplus.sos-pharmacie-de-garde.com/js/sos.js) .
Here is part of the code that has custom jquery CLButton methods. Here i

```
CLButton.prototype = {
        constructor: CLButton,
        ...                             
        hideLoader: function(){
            var $loader = this.getLoader();
            var $bg = $loader.find(".bg");
            $loader.fadeOut(150, function(){
                $bg.css({'width':'252px','height':'auto'});
            });
        },
```

..

In document.read there is the following code:

```
// creates CLButton and shows some staff
$("#next2").CLButton({
    'delay'      : 3000,
    'formSubmit' : false,
    'txtWait'    : 'Chargement en cours ...'
  });
```

This code runs on button #next2 click and do som staff. I believe that now I need to run `hideLoader` method (see above), but I do not understand how .
I should try to call `hideLoader` method inside this script:

```
 $("#next2").click(function(){
   ... //HOW TO CALL hideLoader here?
 }
```

The question is -  how to do this? Object is created outside `click` function in document.ready. So I need somehow access this object and then call method defined above. How?

Answer (score 0):

From the linked code:

```
    onClick : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.disable();
        setTimeout($.proxy(this, '_callback', 'onClick', e), this.settings.delay);
        return false;
    },

    _callback: function(callback, e){
        this.settings[callback].call(this, e);
        if (callback == 'onClick' && this.settings.formSubmit){
            this.canSubmitForm = true;
            this.$form.submit();
        }
    },
```

This seems to indicate that you can pass in a click handler as an option, e.g.

```
$("#next2").CLButton({
    'callback' : function () {
         // stuff to do onclick
     },
     // other options here
});
```

But if you want to change the source of CLButton, you could do this:

```
_callback: function(callback, e){
    this.hideLoader(); // add this call here
    this.settings[callback].call(this, e);
    if (callback == 'onClick' && this.settings.formSubmit){
        this.canSubmitForm = true;
        this.$form.submit();
    }
},
```